# putting tables side by side without removing background from div

Tags: html, css

I have several tables that I want to put side by side, however when I use the float left property, it removes the background color from the div it is in.  Any ideas how I could put the tables side by side without removing the background?  It's like it don't even enter the div when I add the float left to the table.

Thanks

heres the div the tables are in

```
 div.middle {
       background-color:#FFF;
       width:960px;
       height:auto;


       margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color:#FFF;
    border-width:medium;
```

heres the html for my table located inside the middel div

```
<table border='1'>\n
<tr><td align='center' colspan = '10'>Division: 8a10 Grupo A</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Equipo</td>
<td>JJ</td>
<td>JG</td>
<td>JP</td>
<td>JE</td>
<td>GF</td>
<td>GC</td>
<td>GD</td>
<td>PTS</td>
</tr>




       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

```
<div style="background-color:blue">
   <table id="table1">...</table>
   <table id="table2">...</table>
   <div style="clear:both"><!-- clear the floats --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but I prefer the `overflow:auto` trick which doesn't require adding extra markup.

Comment: well the question arises whether overflow:auto is actually supposed to do what it's doing. It looks like a CSS hack and browser quirk to me and that means potential future breakage.

Comment: Actually I found the relevant piece of spec, looks like the overflow method may be legal CSS, though I find the terminology a bit unclear: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float`, the element is taken out of the "flow" and the outer element will often appear to be shorter than its parent.

An easy fix is to apply `overflow: auto;` to the outer div.

Here's [a good post about this issue and fix](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using float so should clear your all floats with parent div.
An easy fix is to apply overflow: auto; to your main parent div like where you are using the background color.

[Overflow:auto trick (auto clear floats)](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/clear-float/)